# Trigonometric equation tangent

Tags: trigonometry

I want to solve trigonometric equation $\tan x=\pi-x$.
one of these solutions in interval [0,$\pi$] is $x=\pi$. Find another root please.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this equation cannot be solved by elemental functions. If you plot the function, you will see that there is a root close to $x = 1$. Then, the numerical solution can be obtained using Newton iterative method which write

$$x_{\text{new}} = x_{\text{old}} - \frac{f(x_{\text{old}})}{ f'(x_{\text{old}})}$$

Starting at $x_{\text{old}} = 1$, the successive iterates will then be 1.13200, 1.11347, 1.11284, 1.11283. You can continue until you reach the desired level of accuracy.